# Is it legal to not get a 1099-b until March 15?

Tags: united-states, stocks, irs, form-1099, corporate-acquisition

It is Feb. 16 and I haven't received a 1099-b for some stocks that sold that last year.  The stocks were sold because the company I had stock in (Questar) merged with another company and all Questar stock was bought out as part of the merger.  These stocks were all purchased directly from the company.

I called the merged company to inquire about this yesterday, Feb. 15. I was connected with a guy who told me that it looks like Wells Fargo (who was in charge of administering the stock and issuing the 1099-b forms) hadn't posted any 1099-b forms yet.  He said Wells Fargo might do so later that night and he'd call me back on Feb. 16 (today) to let me know if Wells Fargo had issued any 1099-b forms yet.

He called me today and said that, at least for as many accounts as he looked at, no 1099-b forms were issued.  He called Wells Fargo and was told by them that there were some complications and that Wells Fargo had until March 15 to issue the 1099-b forms.

**I would like to know, are there any situations in which issuers of 1099-b forms are given a later deadline of March 15 to issue those forms?**  I'm not asking if that makes sense specifically in this situation (although if you have comments about that I would appreciate it) but whether this is even a situation that can exist.  Perhaps the situation with the company-wide stock buyout complicated things, though I don't see how.

Would a call to the IRS help encourage Wells Fargo to get these forms issued sooner?

Unfortunately I don't have enough information myself to accurately fill out the information on my 1040.  The stocks were slowly purchased over decades via a dividend reinvestment plan.

Comment: For what it is worth, Ameriprise says [on their website](https://www.ameriprise.com/research-market-insights/tax-center/filing-resources/tax-statement-mailing-dates/) that they will send out the 1099-B (and other forms) for brokerage accounts that hold REMICs, CDOs, WHFITs, or WHMTs by March 15.  I doubt they'd post that on their website if it wasn't legal.

Comment: Would you prefer a single final 1099 in March or one in Feb and then a corrected one in March. I remember one year in which I had a revised 1099 for my revised 1099. Typical advice for those with investments is not to file until mid March so that you don't have to deal with amended returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If one looks at the "[Guide to Information Returns](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1099gi/ar01.html#en_US_2017_publink1000287056)" in the Form 1099 General Instructions (the instructions that the IRS provides to companies on how to fill out 1099 and other forms), it says that the 1099-B is due to recipient by February 15, with a footnote that says "The due date is March 15 for reporting by trustees and middlemen of WHFITs." I doubt that exception applies, though it may. There's also a section in the instructions on "[Extension of time to furnish statements to recipients](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1099gi/ar01.html#d0e1737)" which says that a company can apply to the IRS to get an extension to this deadline if needed. I'm guessing that if you were told that there were "complications" that they may have applied for and been given this extension, though that's just a guess.

While you could try calling the IRS if you want (and in fact, their web site [does suggest calling them](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc154.html) if you don't receive a W-2 or 1099-R by the end of February), my honest opinion is that they won't do much until mid-March anyway. Unfortunately, you're probably out of luck being able to file as early as you want to.

Answer (score 5):

The deadline to mail is [February 15](https://www.thebalance.com/income-tax-deadlines-3192862). However, if the [form is being prepared by a middleman](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1099gi.pdf) (i.e. Wells Fargo) then they have until March 15th (on page 24). Also, if you haven't received your 1099 form by [February 14](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2664174-how-to-file-if-you-haven-t-received-1099), you may contact the IRS and they will contact and request the missing form on your behalf. I know that's a lot of information, but to answer your question, yes, there are situations where March 15th is the deadline instead of February 15th.